# How can I have php execute a shell script as a user other than www-data

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, apache2, php

I have a user called gmodserver which manages a garrys mod server. The manager script only works properly when its executed using that user. I want to make a php enabled site that allows people with a special key to restart the server.

Therefore I need a way to run that script using "gmodserver" as the user. 
How can I do that?

Comment: You can do this by `sudo -u gmodserver command`, but first configure sudo to allow www-data to do it. Configure to not have root access but only access to this user/command.

Comment: @LeonidMew Yes I did that correctly now but the server doesnt seem to correctly identify the server now. Here is the thing. If I have php run whoami it returns "gmodserver" which is correct, but if I run anything with the lgsm script that runs the server it acts like it needs to start a NEW server and ignores the existing one. Why could this be happening ( some educated guesses maybe? )